# Smart search indexer hangs

Tags: joomla-3.x, smartsearch

I want to use smart search. But my indexer won't finish indexing.
I’ve enabled the smart search plugin.
Made a custom smart search plugin.
When I hit the index button, joomla starts indexing VERY slow after about 25% it stops.
I’ve googled and googled… Others have this problem, but nobody seems to come up with an answer.
I’ve tried adjusting the Indexer Batch Size to 5, and 100 and so on.
I’ve tried adjusting the tab Index to 3000 and 30.
I’ve tried changing the log path.
I’ve change my php version from 5.2 to 5.5.
I’ve change session time from 15 to 55 to 555 and so on.
… and every time the same happens, indexer stops at 25% or so.
Hope someone help me?

Solution!!
Somehow, I was able to index my local website, so I've imported the local database the the live one. I know this isn't a perfect solution. However it must do for now.
The live website should be an exact copy of the local one, so I have no idea of where difference are.

Comment: Is PHP logging any errors?

Comment: How do I see if php is logging errors?

Comment: Is there an error_log file, or error.log file somewhere on the server? Does cPanel or Apache report anything in their logs?

Comment: ... or put the site error logging to Development in the backend configuration, you'll see errors printed on video. remember to turn it back to default when you're done.

Comment: The only thing it says is:  [Tue May 13 10:01:48 2014] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the solution!

Here the original topic from  joomla.forum.org:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=803468

Tutorial for CLI:

http://docs.joomla.org/Setting_up_automatic_Smart_Search_indexing